# Sorting rendered edges

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is there a way how to control the sequence in which the edges are rendered between two nodes in a multigraph? I need a way how to tell the renderer that the edges should be rendered in a particular order between two nodes, let's say I want first render the edges from node_1 to node_2 and then the edges from node_2 to node_1 so the picture is more readable (it's quite important in my use case). It would be also great to have the possibility to sort them by a property stored on edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the elements in the order you want them.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Just to clarify: the sorting is based on the id (sorted by id) or is it strictly based on the order the edges were added to the model?

Comment: Bundled beziers are sorted by the order they were added --- only.